# typescript callback with generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, callback

I have the following code:

```js
type callbackType = <T>(d: T) => void;

const callbackTest = <T>(val: T, callback: callbackType) => {
    callback(val);
};

callbackTest("Hey", isAString => isAString)
```

Here I would expect Typescript to deduce that `isAString` has the type `string`, which it doesn't.

if i inline the `callbackType` like so:

```js
const callbackTest = <T>(val: T, callback: (d: T) => void) => {
    callback(val);
};

callbackTest("Hey", isAString => isAString)
```

Typescript can deduce that `isAString` has the type `string`.

I Tryed adding a `<T>` behind `callbackType` (`callback: callbackType<T>`), but this doesn't seem to be valid Typescript and gives the following error: `Type 'callbackType' is not generic.`

In my real code `callbackType`  is a more complex function that I use multiple times, therefore inlining it wouldn't be ideal.

Any ideas how I could help Typescript figure out the type of `isAString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the generic to the type from the function:

```
type callbackType<T> = (d: T) => void;
```

Then you can pass `T` to the type like you originally tried:

```
const callbackTest = <T>(val: T, callback: callbackType<T>) => {
    callback(val);
};

callbackTest("Hey", isAString => isAString);
```